# Connect-PnPOnline - A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs

I am trying to connect to a sharepoint site from a PowerShell job running in an Azure App Service, whenever i try to connect it gives me the following error:

```
Authentication failed: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
```

When looking in the source code for the method Connect-PnPOnline for the positional parameter -Credentials it expects a CredentialPipeBind, which is a class [public sealed class CredentialPipeBind](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Base/PipeBinds/CredentialPipeBind.cs)

The class looks like it's meant to switch between a credential from the windows credential manager, or a powershell credential object.
The Azure job may be wanting to get the literal type from the positional parameter?
I tried giving it a

```
Function Set-SpsConnection ($url, $creds) {
    $crpb = [SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PipeBinds.CredentialPipeBind]::new($creds)
    Connect-PnPOnline –Url $sharepointurl –Credentials $crpb
}
```

But to no avail, now it thinks i'm using `SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PipeBinds.CredentialPipeBind` instead of `CredentialPipeBind`, maybe I can somehow reference the assembly so that i don't have to specify?

The issue seems to only appear when it is ran by a job or i start the script in the Kudu Console with .\scriptname.ps1 , when I execute the code in the Kudu console Copy-Paste it seems to work fine...

In my opinion this just seems like an inherent flaw within the azure job system, that it will only interpret litteral types and not run the same as on a client.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, if you want to connect to a sharepoint site with Credentials in PowerShell, the parameter `Credentials`   should be a PSCredential object or a string(the cert name credentials from the Windows Credential Manager). For more details, please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps#parameters) the [issue](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/connect-pnponline-credential-can-it-use/m-p/78403#) and the [document](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/ad7e28e90754e4bdfdb1a40a8269cfa9425d7eff/Commands/Base/ConnectOnline.cs#L225)
[image]

For example

```
$name = "username"
$password = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://hanxia.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $mycreds
Get-PnPList
```

[image]

---

## update

According to my test, we can run the script in Azure web job

1. Update the module to Azure vai kuduo
   [image]
   [image]
2. Create a web job. My script is as below

```
$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Import-Module '<the path of your module>\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline' -DisableNameChecking
$name = "username"
$password = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<>.sharepoint.com/ -Credentials $mycreds

Get-PnPList
```

[image]

Comment: No see this is what should be the expected behaviour, if you were to try this in an Azure webjob it would fail, as it expects a different value.
I would have to create a CredentialPipeBind perhaps, but it feels as if this could be a bug...

Comment: When I run your isolated code it seems to work, however (something) is making it so that it does not work when trying with my code. I'm going to do some more tests and see if I can figure it out...

Comment: @ThomErnst Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: It won't fix the inherent problem that seems to happen, it feels like i need to make a lot of new methods for every single action otherwise it does not work. I can't seem to understand the problem so I can't explain why it won't work either...